# Is "use strict" useful in Node version 14?

Tags: node.js

I have updated from **Node.js 12.19** to **Node.js 14.15**

Does it still make a difference to use the `use strict` line?

Does it guarantee the latest features?

Comment: If you're using modules, then all your code is automatically running in strict mode. Same if you have just a global thing but you have a class, for example. In general, any code written in a purely ES6 construct (class, generator, module, etc.) will be automatically parsed as strict. Not sure if Node makes any other changes on top of that, like making *everything* strict but perhaps it doesn't need to.

Comment: `use strict` doesn't guarantee any features. `use strict` changes some rules how code is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any detailed documentation about whether `use strict` mode is enabled or not on a certain version. But I'm using Node v16.20.1 (with `type: "module"` in my package.json) and I found [this blog post](http://imaginativethinking.ca/what-the-heck-is-node-modules-strict-by-default/) that gave me a good test which I ran to tell me `use strict` is **definitely enabled by default** at least with Node 16 when `type: module` is set.

I created 2 test files in my project:

**test.js:**

```
'use strict';
import mod from './myModule.js';

function local(arg) {
  console.log('Local');
  console.log(`${arg} -- ${arguments[0]}`);
  arguments[0] = 20;
  console.log(`${arg} -- ${arguments[0]}`);
}

local(10);
mod(10);
```

**myModule.js**:

```
export default function(arg) {
  console.log('Mod')
  console.log(`${arg} -- ${arguments[0]}`);
  arguments[0] = 20;
  console.log(`${arg} -- ${arguments[0]}`);
}
```

And the output when I ran it was:

```
C:\myproject> node ./test.js
Local
10 -- 10
10 -- 20
Mod
10 -- 10
10 -- 20
```

If you run this test and it shows `20 -- 20` as the last line, then you know that you need `use strict` at the top of your files to enable strict mode. If it it's `10 -- 20`, then it's enabled by default.